# odd type inference issue with 'validation', in F#

Tags: f#, rider

using the lib 'FsToolkit.ErrorHandling'

and the following code:

```
let f x =
    if x % 2 = 0 then Ok $"even {x}" else Error $"odd {x}"

let xx =
    validation {

        let! a = f 1
        and! b = f 2
        and! c = f 3

        return $"{a} {b} {c}"
    }

printfn $"{xx.GetType()}"
```

The output is a

> Result<string, string list>

Or, more specifically:

> Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpResult`2[System.String,Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[System.String]]

But the IDE (Rider) sees it differently:

[image]

Is this an expected behavior for some reason? or could it be a bug?

Comment: Is `Validation<'a, 'b>` a type alias for `Result<'a, 'b list>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Validation<'a, 'err>` is a type alias for `Result<'a, 'err list>`:

https://github.com/demystifyfp/FsToolkit.ErrorHandling/blob/f5019f10c4418426a2e182377be06beecd09876b/src/FsToolkit.ErrorHandling/Validation.fs#L3

This doesn't create a new type but creates a new way to refer to an existing type, which means that they can be used interchangeably.

Comment: ah ok, that makes sense now